# Java post form in JSP, get parameter in servlet returns NULL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm having a problem with a simple Java form submission.

I have my login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>The best login page in the world</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Connexion</h1>
        <form id="asdasd" name="coucou" method="post" action="doLogin">
            <input type="text" name="user_email" />
            <input type="password" name="user_password" />
            <input type="submit" name="asd" value="Se connecter" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

my web.xml specifiying that doLogin in infact the servlet loginServlet

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.courses.web.servlet.loginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/doLogin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And my loginServlet.java

```
public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String username = req.getParameter("user_email");
        String password = req.getParameter("user_password");

        Console console = System.console();
        console.printf("mail : %s\npassword: %s\n", username,password);

    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

Nothing really complicated but the variable that I get from getParameter are always NULL and I don't know why.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Which URL are you accessing to display your login view?

Comment: Also, since you're already using JSF, why not use it also for your login view? This way you save too much development time. By the way, if you happen to use JSF 2, I recommend you changing the URL pattern for the Faces Servlet to `*.xhtml` or to `*.jsp` instead of the old `/faces/*`.

Comment: I access it from http://localhost:8080/[projectname]/login.jsp . I'm quite new to Java, what would using JSF change to my login view ?

Comment: I tried, didn't change anything

Comment: Thank god it didn't work, that would mean your server is broken. At this point I would use a plugin for your browser (or any built in feature) to track the HTTP traffic that is being sent and received to see what is actually in there; what you have is just correct and should work!

Comment: Are you running your server in your IDE e.g. Eclipse, Netbeans, etc, or in a real console like command prompt from Windows or Linux console?

Comment: Yeah, I'm running glassfish in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted a stacktrace, the only line that can have return a `null` value is this one:

```
Console console = System.console();
```

Noted by your comment: *I'm running glassfish in Netbeans*. So, this line will throw a `NullPointerException`:

```
console.printf("mail : %s\npassword: %s\n", username,password); //console is null
```

Try using a logger instead to print your messages. Just for a dirty quick solution, use `System.out.println` instead until you happen to configure and use a logger. So, in short, replace these lines:

```
Console console = System.console();
console.printf("mail : %s\npassword: %s\n", username,password);
```

To:

```
System.out.printf("mail : %s\npassword: %s\n", username,password));
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this; you say the OP is mistakenly reporting an NPE as parameters being null. You may just be right.

Comment: WEll that was it, how come that it wasn't working ? The pointer shouldn't have been null since it was poiting to a variable that had a value ...

Comment: @JayZus `System.console` returns a variable pointing to the current console where the Java application is running. Since you're running GlassFish from Netbeans console (which is not a real console), it will return `null`.